# iOS App compatible with all device versions

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've been developing apps for iPhone and iPad for quite some time now and i am developing each for each versions of the device because i am afraid that it will not run on lower versions without the retina display.

Is there a way to develop an app that will work on all versions of the device?? because now the new iPhone and iPad is coming out with iOS6.

Comment: The iPad Mini, set to be released by October i think.

Comment: We have no official announcement from Apple about a new iPad. If it exists, we know nothing about its software. So speculation is useless at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, older versions of apps will work with the new iOS6. The apps that are crated for older versions will be letter boxed however. I would say to create an app for the 3GS first and test it's compatibility. You may be missing some of the essential functions that come on the newer devices. My suggestion is to create a universal app.

Answer (score 0):

The older apps will work fine on the new iOS6. Since the new iphone5 has high aspect ratio, the old  apps would be letterboxed i.e run with black border. For more information you can visit http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/12/first-party-apple-apps-optimized-for-iphone-5-display-existing-apps-will-run-letterboxed/

Answer (score 0):

A universal app is one which the binary will run on both the iPad and iPhone.  The customer buys it for one device, and automatically can run it on both devices.  There might be a business reason to have two different versions of an App (one for iPhone, the other for iPad).  From the customer perspective, it is nicer to buy it only once.  Some game developers justify it, because the graphics have to be redone for the much larger size of the iPad, which can take a lot of time.

The issue regarding the retina display has to do with the assets you include in your App.  Usually for UIKit based Apps, by appending "@2x.png" to a filename signifies that the asset is to be used on Retina capable devices.  Otherwise, the device will automatically double the size of a normal sized image.  This page has more info on it:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

The other issue when you mention "all versions of a device", has to do with the version of iOS.  If you do not make use of newer frameworks, you can usually allow an app to easily be backwards compatible.  You can write an App to check for which version of iOS it is running, and then dynamically link to these libraries and do it at run time, and then not support certain features that were not available on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can either choose to go for 'lowest common denominator', OR...

target the latest and greatest device and be prepared to write code to selectively disable features, support multiple resolutions and instruction sets, and accept the massive amount of testing this will entail.

Lowest common denominator is, trivially, an application compiled on a modern xcode targetted at the iPhone 1.  It will run on all subsequent platforms, but will have the following 'issues':

- black box or bars around the interface on iPhone5, iPad.
- pixel-looking graphics on all iPads and iPhone 4+
- no camera support
- no GPS support
- no compass support
- no multi-tasking or push notifications
- no built-in fast email/messaging support
- no social network support
- no gamecenter support
- etc - see any apple feature list.

If you want to support any of the above, you can always test to see if the device supports the particular API, function or resolution - Apple's developer documentation is very helpful on this.

---

Note: you don't have to select iPhone 1 as the lowest common denominator - the 3GS would be a good choice as well, since it was available for sale until pretty recently.